# changing string format into date

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I need to change string into date format 'YYYY-MM-DD'
Input data is

```
20180716
20180912
```

like this in string type and need output as

```
2018-07-16
2018-09-12

spark.sql("""select TO_DATE(CAST(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(MYDAT, 'yyyyMMdd') AS TIMESTAMP)) AS reg_datefrom Table  """)
```

query for above output is

```
reg_date
null    
null    
null    
null    
null
```

But when I am writing below code its working.

```
spark.sql("""
  SELECT TO_DATE(CAST(UNIX_TIMESTAMP('20180811', 'yyyyMMdd') AS TIMESTAMP)) AS newdate"""
).show()

Output:

+----------+ | newdate| +----------+ |2018-08-11| +----------+
```

Where I am doing mistake.

Comment: show the output of query `select MYDAT,TO_DATE(CAST(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(MYDAT, 'yyyyMMdd') AS TIMESTAMP)) AS reg_date from Table`

Comment: Do you have `MYDAT` column in table

Answer (score 0):

In Spark, we can write the `TO_DATE('20180811', 'yyyyMMdd')` function by passing the date format of the string value that passing to `TO_DATE` function and returns the date as `yyyy-MM-dd`

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this at my end, this is working however I feel 2 possibilities looking at your snippet

1. Please check your MYDAT column is string
2. in ur query reg_datefrom is concatnated, seprate it